# WebGL via remote desktop in latest Jessie on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian-jessie, web-browsers, web, opengles

Hello Raspberry Pi enthusiasts!

I have a problem, I can't seem to get a webgl context running on a chromium browser instance using latest Jessie on a Raspberry pi 3.
I have enabled experimental GL drivers and I am sending all kinds of enable flags to chromium when I start it, no dice.
When I run chromium-browser from terminal it says something about glGetQueryVerX crashing (can't copy right now at work sorry).
I have the latest mesa drivers from the default package source for jessie.

When I look at chrome://gpu it says that all gpu features are disabled, because chrome://settings have disabled them, yeah, no.

I have two questions: 
1) Is the current state of webgl on Raspberry pi with the mesa drivers confirmed borked?

2) Is there any know way to run a webgl context on any browser for jessie debian built for ARMv7?

I'd rather not have to resort to SDL2.

**I am using a remote desktop to access the browser.**

Comment: Probably no way to get that working currently.

Comment: Edit rejected. WebGL **=** OpenGL ES *2*. Linked question is pretty much the same as your question. Oh, and if I were you, I wouldn't attack a mod.

Answer (score 0):

Same poster, different account.

Anyway, my problem in particular turned out to be that I was accessing the web page through an remote desktop session. This made webgl not able to identify which screen to whatever kind of magic it needs to do.

So make sure to try with a screen connected to the hdmi port of the pi.